# Add Password confirmation if Button is pressed

Tags: java, android, password-protection

How do I add a password confirmation if i press a Button.
Its for Android API19.

edited and answered:

- "A dialog sounds great."
- "I don´t have any Idea how to Imagine that."

I think about doing so.

1. Press Button
2. need to Enter Password
3. if password is correct, continue with code. setImageSource etc.
4. if password is incorrect, do nothing.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: what you want a dialog, your question is broad.

Comment: Try it out and report back if any problems show up :)

Comment: I havn´t think about it yet but a dialog sounds great.

Comment: I don´t have any Idea how to Imagine that.

Comment: **1**. You should enter the password then only press `button`. **2**. `Toast` already good enough if password correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a password confirmation before the button? If you really want to do it, dialog is a good choice. Customize a view with `TextInputLayout`, add `setNegativeButton()` and `setPositiveButton()`, handle you request in `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and so on. You can also hide the confirmation component and show it after the button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

okay ive done it so.

in layout file

```
    <Button
    ...
    android:onClick="makechanges" />
```

in java class

```
boolean passwordentered = false;

makechanges (View view)
{
        if (passwordentered == false)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder1.setMessage("You havn´t entered password!");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                "Enter Password",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        setContentView(R.layout.layouttoenterpw);
                    }
                });

            builder1.setNegativeButton(
                "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Keypass not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
}
        else if (buycentfunfzig == true)
        {
            euroset = R.drawable.centfunfzig;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ImageView picturetochange= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iveuro);
            picturetochange.setImageResource(euroset);
        }
```

and in new layout i made a textfield for enter password, a send button with onClick and a back button.